# Does Xcode 4.4 come with subversion?

Tags: svn, xcode4.4

I've just downloaded Xcode 4.4, and unlike its predecessors, there's no installer, just a `.app`. Is subversion lurking in there somewhere? Is there a directory inside the `.app` that I can add to `PATH` to get all my command line tools back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the Command Line tools from XCode preferences and it all works again.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I've found it, you need to add the following to your `PATH` (assuming Xcode is installed in your Applications folder):

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
```

Comment: I believe Xcode4.4 is still under NDA (it's a developer preview)?

Comment: I just purchased Mountain Lion and, upon attempting to install command line tools through Preferences -> Downloads, I got this error: "<account name> does not have access to command line tools".  This was the solution to my problem.  Thanks Tom Medley!

Comment: Wrong; you install the command line utilities and use `xcode-select`.

Comment: This solves my problem of unable to install the command line tools

Comment: @Espilon that was a problem with the Apple servers, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

As of OS X 10.5 Leopard, Subversion is installed with the operating system. No need to change anything or set anything up specially.

Comment: This definitely isn't true with Mountain Lion. In fact upgrading actually *deleted* my svn installation - had to use xcode 'install command line tools' to put it back