# Source control with Xcode 4.4

Tags: xcode, version-control

I was using Xcode 4.3 and Subversion (SVN) for source control. Everything was working fine. I was able to see the files I've changed, compare with server version and commit.

Then Xcode 4.4 was released and I downloaded the new version and installed it. Now, source control has stopped to work. I don't see the files I've changed, and it seems that source control is not enabled.

Things I've already tried:

- Delete all files from my local folder and use "Connect to repository" option on the XCode initial screen
- Download everything from server with command line as I always did

Did anyone have any problem regarding source control?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Xcode 4.4 come with subversion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326647/does-xcode-4-4-come-with-subversion)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm answering your question here or a slightly different one, but I'd been searching around for an answer to a similar question - I would set up a new project in Xcode, then using svn command-line tools put it up on my svn repo; however in Xcode 4.4 (unlike its predecessors) this would **not** subsequently allow me to use the Xcode svn controls (my favourite being the Version editor panes).

The answer for me was to close the project, delete the project's derived data (Organizer -> Projects -> Select correct project -> Hit "Delete" button in line with "Derived Data") - then load up the project again.

Apologies if this does not in fact address your issue, but Xcode 4.4 seems to have introduced a few bugs regarding source control so perhaps this will assist in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Support for using Source Control in xcode is mostly aimed at new/fresh starts in xCode. Aligning existing projects with the changes is less well explained. I found this partly helpful http://asciiwwdc.com/2013/sessions/414 but ponderous. Muddling on gave the best result.